# New vs Override

Tags: c#

Qual seria a diferença entre new e override ? 
Exemplos:
Override:

```
public class ClasseBase
{
    public virtual void Funcao ()
    {

    }
}
public class Classe : ClasseBase
{
     public override void Funcao()
     {

     }
}
```

New:

```
public class ClasseBase
{
    public void Funcao()
    {

    }
}
public class Classe : ClasseBase
{
     public new void Funcao()
     {

     }
}
```

Existe uma diferença entre o `new` e o `override`? Eu sei que o `new` pode ser usado para instanciar uma classe e o `override` não, mas se existe uma diferença, qual é?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A diferença é que se o método for declarado com `new` não é polimórfico ao passo que com `override` é.

Logo `override` dá uma nova implementação ao método da classe base, e `new` é como se fosse um método diferente do da classe base apesar de ter o mesmo nome.

Pegando no seu exemplo:

```
public class ClasseBase
{
    public virtual void Funcao()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Classe : ClasseBase
{
    public override void Funcao() //com override
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derivada");
    }
}

public class Classe2 : ClasseBase
{
    public new void Funcao() //com new
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derivada2");
    }
}
```

Quando criamos os objetos e guardamos numa variável do tipo dessa classe, tudo funciona normalmente:

```
 Classe c1 = new Classe();
 Classe2 c2 = new Classe2();

 c1.Funcao(); //Derivada
 c2.Funcao(); //Derivada2
```

Mas quando guardamos no tipo da classe base e esperamos que o polimorfismo atue, executando o código das classes derivadas vemos que isso só acontece com `override`:

```
ClasseBase c3 = new Classe();
ClasseBase c4 = new Classe2();

c3.Funcao(); //Derivada
c4.Funcao(); //Base
```

Aqui apenas em `c3` a chamada foi polimórfica executando o método `Funcao` da `Classe` em vez de `ClasseBase` que era o tipo da variável.

[Veja o exemplo no .netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3beK3F)

O `new` permite dar uma nova implementação a um método **não virtual** da classe base, escondendo assim a implementação da base.

Exemplo:

```
public class ClasseBase
{
    public void Funcao() //não virtual
    {
    }
}

public class Derivada 
{
    public new void Funcao()
    {
    }
}
```

Algo que o próprio Visual Studio indica quando vê uma função igual à da classe base sendo essa não virtual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se reparar atentamente na imagem irá ver que é um aviso e não um erro, o que faz com que não seja estritamente obrigatório neste caso, apesar de dar mais legibilidade e clareza ao código.

Documentação para o [`new`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) e [`override`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

Referências:

- [Quando usar as palavras-chave override e new](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) (Créditos: Virgilio Novic)

Comment: aqui tem uma boa referencia: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords se quiser claro adicionar!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim claro. Agradeço o comentário e a referência.