# O que é e para que serve um Override (sobrescrita de método) na programação?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, polimorfismo

O título da pergunta basicamente diz tudo: o que é e para que serve um *Override* (sobrescrita de método) na programação?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a finalidade da @Override?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [@override é obrigatório em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [New vs Override \[duplicada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237930/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Pode-se fazer override em construtores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128233/3774)

Comment: Editei a pergunta filtrando todo conteúdo que era ruído e não acrescentava à pergunta (que era basicamente tudo). Não precisa esclarecer na pergunta que irá também postar a resposta; ao fazer isso já ficará explícito. Também removi a tag "profgramação-funcional" porque não vi relação alguma com o paradigma funcional, bem como adicionei a tag de orientação a objetos.

Comment: Obrigado pelas alterações!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [@override é obrigatório em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33014/override-%c3%a9-obrigat%c3%b3rio-em-java)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a finalidade da @Override?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22913/qual-a-finalidade-da-override)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substituição de método , na programação **orientada a objetos** , é um recurso de linguagem que permite que uma **subclasse** ou **classe filho** forneça uma implementação específica de um método que já é **fornecido por uma de suas superclasses ou classes pai**.

A implementação na subclasse substitui a implementação na **superclasse**, fornecendo um **método que tem o mesmo nome**, os mesmos parâmetros ou assinatura e o mesmo tipo de retorno que o método na **classe pai**.

A versão de um método que é executado será determinada pelo objeto isso é usado para invocá-lo. Se um objeto de uma classe pai for usado para invocar o método, a versão na **classe pai** será executada, mas se um objeto da **subclasse** for usado para invocar o método, a versão na **classe filho** será executada.

**Algumas linguagens** permitem que um programador impeça a substituição de um método.

A principal **vantagem** da substituição de método é que a classe pode dar sua própria implementação específica a um método herdado sem modificar o código da classe pai .

Comment: Dei +1 mas não está inteiramente correto. A sobrescrita pode ser de um método abstrato, neste caso não há implementação na classe-pai.

Comment: Obrigado, este estudo foi feita minutos antes deste post, mas obrigado pela informação!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine que você tenha uma classe **base** chamada **Pessoa**, com vários atributos que toda pessoa necessariamente deve conter, como cargo, idade, nome, e um método chamado **PagamentoSalario()**.

Todas as pessoas necessitam ter seu salário pago através deste método, porém sabemos que os salários para cada pessoa diferem muito, a depender do cargo, região e vários outros fatores.

Podemos então, **sobrescrever** o método **PagamentoSalario()** que foi herdada da classe base **Pessoa**, e alterar a lógica da mesma. Note que ainda estamos herdando este método, mantendo seus parâmetros, seu nome, e seu tipo de retorno (se houver algum), porém podemos especificar como que esta função deverá se comportar na classe a qual sobrescrevemos o método.

O método na classe **base** não irá ser alterado, e todas as outras classes que herdarem desta, ainda terão este método e também poderão sobrescrever o mesmo caso haja necessidade.